# Problema al actualizar android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un problema con mi `Android Studio`. Tengo la versión 1.3 y cuando busco actualizaciones me dice que ya está actualizado, ¿Alguna manera de actualizarlo al 1.5.1?

Comment: haz tratado de descargarlo nuevamente por completo?

Comment: de donde lo descargo nuevamente completo?

Comment: Yo te recomiendo bajarte Android Studio 2.0 RC2, las mejoras son sustanciales, seleccionas el anillo estable si no quieres estar actualizando cada 3 dias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes descargar Android studio por completo, desde [este link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Puedes mantener tu SDK y APIs instaladas, solo dile a la nueva version de Android studio donde tienes el Android SDK.

En mi Mac, esta aca (en ingles):

Android -> Preferences -> Appearance & behavior -> System settings -> Android SDK

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si lo vuelvo a descargar, tengo que volver a instalar todas las apis?

Comment: no, pero si vas a tener que decirle a la nueva version donde tienes el android sdk

Comment: Menos mal, disculpame mi ignorancia, pero. Donde esta normalmente el SDK?

Comment: actualize mi respuesta con una imagen y la ubicacion del android sdk en mi mac

Comment: tengo una duda, desinstalo primero el android studio que tengo antes de instalar el nuevo?

Comment: si no esta funcionando bien, seria mejor desinstalarlo e instalar la version nueva desde 0

Comment: el IDE funciona bien, el unico problema que tengo es que no puedo actualizarlo, lo desinstalo de todas formas?

Comment: si fuera mi computador, la respuesta es si. no se por que no puedes actualizar AS, por lo que instalar una version sobre la existente puede mantener el problema de actualizacion que tienes hoy

Comment: Muchas gracias por la paciencia. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El sitio oficial para instalar Android Studio para PC ó MAC es:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/index.html

Cuando se tiene un problema con Android Studio **no es opción desinstalar todo y volver a instalar**, Android Studio ahora es mucho más estable y más dificil de corromper que Eclipse.

Si se descargan los paquetes o API´s no se necesitan descargar nuevamente, ya que se descargan en la ruta donde se encuentra el SDK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso puedes cambiar la ruta del SDK o cambiar a otra versión desde las preferencias:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Tu problema lo pudiste solucionar únicamente cambiando a los "canales estables" y activando la actualización nuevamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cambie a los canales estables antes de solucionar el problema Elena, pero tampoco lo podia actualizar.